# I found a reference to ‘naysmith’ in a work of science fiction. Is anybody familiar with the term?

Tags: nouns

I could not find any references to ‘naysmith’ as an actual historical term.  Following is an excerpt from the book ‘Horus Rising.”

> ‘Then it occurs to me, Garviel, that only a weapon which questions its use could be of any value in that role. To be a member of the Mournival, you need to have concerns. You need to have wit, and most certainly you need to have doubts. Do you know what a naysmith is?’
>
> ‘No.’
>
> ‘In early Terran history, during the dominance of the Sumaturan dynasts, naysmiths were employed by the ruling classes. Their job was to disagree. To question everything. To consider any argument or policy and find fault with it, or articulate the counter position. They were highly valued.’

- Horus Rising, pg. 68

Comment: Nope...it sounds like a portmanteau of _nay_ (meaning "No") and _smith_ as in "wordsmith". ...close to Devil's Advocate, or maybe some kind of Greek chorus. Sci-fi writers often invent their own words (neologisms) to give a sense of futuristic verisimilitude.

Comment: It is obviously an invented word for the purposes of what sounds like a really good story. You should be aware that Nasmith (pronounced naysmith) is a family name in the UK. Not all of the members of that family would regard disagreeing with everything as a virtue.

Comment: Naysmith is a proper name (surname) in the English speaking world. Spelled Nasmith or Naysmith, it derives from an archaic name for the occupation of cutler. My local member of Parliament was Douglas Naysmith from 1997 to 2010.

Comment: Also *Naismith* (e.g., as in the inventor of basketball) and *Nesmith* (e.g., of The Monkees band fame).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think "Naismith" is mentioned as one of the pseudonyms used by the immortal protagonist of vanVogt's sci-fi classic *The Weapon Shops of Isher*.  And it is the name of a character in Damon Knight's *Beyond the Barrior* (see http://mporcius.blogspot.com/2014/08/beyond-barrier-by-damon-knight.html).

Comment: @GregLee, also a pseudonym of Miles Vorkosigan in Lois McMaster Bujold's novels.

Comment: My impression, when seeing the word in the title of the question was the same as @Cascabel's. It may not be a word, but its meaning and etymology are nevertheless clear.

Comment: It sounds like a *naysmith* is a professional [*naysayer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer).

Comment: That passage looks like a bit of classic exposition. He asks 'do you know what a naysmith is?' and explains then exactly what it means in the context of the story. The occupational-name meaning doesn't seem to be the usage here.

Comment: to naysay, to say no: to naysmith: to fabricate disagreement as a profession.

Comment: Just slogged through close to 400 hits for "naysmith" in Google Books.  In every case, where I could actually view the text, the use was as a surname.  Many of the references were to the steam hammer inventor and members of his family.  Interestingly, beginning around 1940 the name became a very popular surname in fiction, particularly science fiction.

Comment: Admiral Naismith of the Dendarii Free Mercenaries is often contrarian.

Comment: @Hot Licks:  I appreciate the effort, and the suggestion to use Google Books for research before I pose a question like this.  It seems that by most accounts that 'naysmith' is a piece of fictional history from a fictional future.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [Cascabel](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160305/cascabel)'s comment that, from the context, this sounds like a portmanteau of "*nay*" (meaning "no") and "*smith*" (possibly in allusion to *blacksmith*, *tinsmith* etc., but possibly more in it's *figurative* use: "*A person who fashions something non-material, such as an attribute, one's destiny, etc.*" [[OED, sense b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182645)]). In other words, someone good at saying "no" or a *Devil's Advocate*.

For the record, the OED does not have an entry for *naysmith*; the closest is [their entry for "*Naysmyth*"](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125218) which comes from *John Naysmith*, 1808–90, a Scottish engineer who invented both a steam hammer (or piledriver) in 1839 and a design of telescope c1942. It makes no mention of either being related to a cutler.

Comment: Thank you.  I came to the same conclusion involving it being a portmanteau.  I also came across all the references every body has provided, but the story alludes to “ancient Earth” (the setting is 30k years in the future) and makes use of “evolved” language that are variations of modern day terms.  I was trying to find the modern day analog for “naysmith” relative to “Sumatran Dynasts.”  I also could not find much relating to Sumatran politics and the use of “professional contrarians.”  It was an intriguing concept, so I was interested in the possible inspiration(s) for the term and culture.

Answer (score 2):

From an out-of-universe perspective, the quoted passage doesn't indicate that the reader is supposed to be familiar with a word "naysmith" any more than the reader is supposed to be familiar with "Sumaturan dynasts" (which as far as I can tell are entirely fictional). The passage goes on to explain what the word means, which is exactly what would happen for an invented term.

I disagree with the suggestion that the use of the fictional term "naysmith" in this book **must** be related to the actually existing surname *Naysmith.* David Robinson's explanation seems plausible, but I think it's not completely certain: I think the only way to know for sure would be to ask Dan Abnett, the author of the book.

Comment: I don't think anyone has said it must be related to the surname, just that it might be.

Comment: @StuartF: What I meant by that line is that I disagree somewhat with this part of David Robinson's answer: "The author was **undoubtedly** aware of the surname Naysmith (in various spellings) and **was playing on** the fact that the original meaning of the name is unguessable". I think it's possible but not certain that the use in *Horus Rising* is an intentional play on the surname.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Michael Harvey, a quick google shows that it is related to cutler. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naysmith

I also found this: https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Naismith

It appears the origin is from "Knifesmith".

Comment: typo: cutlery, not cutler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear here that it is a profession made up from *nay* "no" and *smith* "someone who makes something professionally" to mean "someone who makes noes professionally". It is not a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) as that means "words blended together", that is, parts of words joined together, as in *motel* from *mot(or hot)el*, whereas this is two complete words joined together, just as *blacksmith* and *goldsmith*.

But it is also clear that it is not simply a neologism. The author was undoubtedly aware of the surname *Naysmith* (in various spellings) and was playing on the fact that the original meaning of the name is unguessable. The author's meaning looks like a plausible meaning for an existing name as it is quite logical that if a goldsmith makes gold things professionally then a naysmith makes nays professionally, just as a naysayer does as an amateur.

Comment: ‘Nay’ is an older form of ‘no.’

Comment: Thank you. @Digcoal. That is the assumption on which my answer is based. But it still exists in some dialects and languages, even if the spelling is not consistent. [See here for Scots](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/nae_adv1) and [here for Dutch, Low German, etc.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nee)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect it is a reference to Bob Naismith.

He is a miniature designer who worked for Citadel Miniature in the 80's. He has notably sculpted the first Space Marine miniature.

Comment: SF writers have a certain talent for slipping names into their works. If you can provide some evidence, I think this would be a winning answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although there was no official Naysmith title, court/royal Jesters often filled this role. Their mandate was to speak unspoken sentiments, no matter the gaffe that would normally be associated. They argued against everything. The trick was doing it in a way that didn't anger everyone enough to have you executed or exiled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).